# Se uma função é muito extensa, é recomendável dividi-la em outras menores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Eu tenho a seguinte função, a qual eu pretendo extende-la:

```
def get_dataframe(site, search):
    if site == 'pichau':
        try:
            soup = get_page(f'https://www.pchau.com.br/catalogsearch/result/?q={search}')
            assert soup

            price_cartao = [i.getText() for i in soup.select('.other .valor')]
            price_boleto = [i.getText().replace('à vista', '') for i in soup.select('.boleto .valor')]
            product = [i.get('title').upper() for i in soup.select('.title a')][:len(price_cartao)]

            data = {'Produto': product, 'Preço à vista': price_boleto, 'Preço cartão': price_cartao}
            product_df = DataFrame(data)
            return product_df

        except Exception as e:
            return 'Problema com a conexão entre o site!'

    elif site == 'chipart':
        try:
            soup = get_page(f'https://www.chipart.com.br/produtos/{search}')
            assert soup

            price_boleto = [i.getText() for i in soup.select('.products__list__item .product-card__price__final .price')]
            price_cartao1 = [i.getText().strip().replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('em', '') for i in soup.select('.products__list__item .installments')]
            price_cartao2 = [i.getText() for i in soup.select('.products__list__item .price-installments .price')]
            product = [i.getText().strip().replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '') for i in soup.select('.product-card__title .title')][:len(price_boleto)]
            price_cartao = [f'{price_cartao1[i]} de {price_cartao2[i]}' for i in range(len(price_boleto))]

            data = {'Produto': product, 'Preço à vista': price_boleto, 'Preço cartão': price_cartao}
            product_df = DataFrame(data)
            return product_df

        except Exception as e:
            return 'Problema com a conexão entre o site!'
```

Nesse caso, o recomendável seria ao invés de dividir em vários ifs "quebrá-la" em várias funções?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

dividir uma função ou não nem sempre está atrelado ao tamanho dela, mas geralmente às etapas de processamento que ela tem.

No seu exemplo claramente temos código repetitivo e que pode ser separado em funções menores especializadas.

Segue uma proposta simplificada de modificação:

```
def get_dataframe(site, search):
    try:
        if site == 'pichau':
            product, price_boleto, price_cartao = pichau(search)
        elif site == 'chipart':
            product, price_boleto, price_cartao = chipart(search)
        else:
            # Se for possivel ter outro valor para site

        data = {'Produto': product, 'Preço à vista': price_boleto, 'Preço cartão': price_cartao}
        product_df = DataFrame(data)
        return product_df

    except Exception as e:
        return 'Problema com a conexão entre o site!'
```

```
def pichau(search):
    soup = get_page(f'https://www.pchau.com.br/catalogsearch/result/?q={search}')
    assert soup

    price_cartao = [i.getText() for i in soup.select('.other .valor')]
    price_boleto = [i.getText().replace('à vista', '') for i in soup.select('.boleto .valor')]
    product = [i.get('title').upper() for i in soup.select('.title a')][:len(price_cartao)]

    return product, price_boleto, price_cartao
```

```
def chipart(search):
    soup = get_page(f'https://www.chipart.com.br/produtos/{search}')
    assert soup

    price_boleto = [i.getText() for i in soup.select('.products__list__item .product-card__price__final .price')]
    price_cartao1 = [i.getText().strip().replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('em', '') for i in soup.select('.products__list__item .installments')]
    price_cartao2 = [i.getText() for i in soup.select('.products__list__item .price-installments .price')]
    product = [i.getText().strip().replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '') for i in soup.select('.product-card__title .title')][:len(price_boleto)]
    price_cartao = [f'{price_cartao1[i]} de {price_cartao2[i]}' for i in range(len(price_boleto))]

    return product, price_boleto, price_cartao
```

Note que a função `get_dataframe` ficou muito mais simples e legível. O que, dependendo do tamanho do projeto, facilita infinitamente a manutenção e aprimoramento.

A parte de retorno das subfunções `pichau` e `chipart` fica à seu critério. Aqui eu preferi retornar os objetos separados para evitar repetição de código. Se preferir, você pode já retornar um dataframe ou um dicionário.

Comment: Valeuzão cara! Eu tava pensando em fazer parecido, mas tava receoso disso ser considerado ineficiente. Não me liguei nas variáveis que estavam sendo repetidas!

Answer (score 0):

Separe-as em módulos. 
A parte boa do python é que você pode instanciá-las apenas no import.

Dependendo do caso, extenda os parâmetros e reaproveite uma função para diferentes tarefas.

Comment: Olá @Mauricio. Se possível coloque código que possa ajudar na sua resposta, fica mais fácil perceber o resultado.